# List of Figures/Tables divided according chapters in abntex2 (memoir) class

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, abnt

I want my list of figures and tables divided according to chapters like this:

```
 Figure 1.1..............
 Figure 1.2..............
 Figure 1.3..............

 Figure 2.1..............
 Figure 2.2..............
 Figure 2.3..............
```

instead of

```
 Figure 1.1..............
 Figure 1.2..............
 Figure 1.3..............
 Figure 2.1..............
 Figure 2.2..............
 Figure 2.3..............
```

I am using the abntex2 class derived of memoir class. I tried to use some tips from other forums, like etoolbox, but they did not work.

Comment: Please provide a MWE as the default in `memoir` is to seperate the figures/tables by chapter as you want. It does not, though, put Figure before the number. Please show us what you have done.

Comment: Book class includes

    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%

in the definition of `\chapter` to add the spaces.

Comment: @John Kormylo so does `memoir` but in the form of a macro `\insertchapterspace` which combines the two pieces of code you mention. If there are other lists, then a simple extension to `\insertchapterspace` can handle spaces in those lists without having to fiddle with the internals of `\chapter`.

Comment: @Peter Wilson, I can't put Figure before the number and I am using the chapterstyle bianchi, it's the template.

Comment: @PeterWilson - I figured KOMA would probably have a different way to do the same thing, but it was late (here) and I was too tired to deal with KOMA.

Comment: @Lara As you haven't provided a MWE as asked we don't know what you have done and I don't see how we can help you.

Comment: @Lara Have you read the user manual? If not, then please look at the `\cftKname{SOMETHING }` macro which lets you put SOMETHING before the K number in the listof, where K is anything from `book` through `figure` and `subtable`.

Comment: This [solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69321/spacing-between-chapters-in-list-of-tables?rq=1) works for figures and tables. But the chapter titles disappear of hyperref mark. :(

Comment: For a while, the solution is use `\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}` and `\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}` after `\chapter`. In the class style, I don't find the definition \@chapter.

Comment: @Lara: Please add a compilable document

Comment: My template is [abntex2](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/abntex2).

Comment: @Lara: We asked you about a compilable document, not the link to the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `abntex2` class uses

`\renewcommand{\insertchapterspace}{}`

i.e. the usage of `\insertchapterspace` is disabled effectively.

The original definition of `\insertchapterspace` in`memoir` is

```
\newcommand*{\insertchapterspace}{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}}
```

i.e. it can be reinjected into the code.

The question is whether the publishers etc. will allow this.

```
\documentclass{abntex2}
\usepackage{pgffor}


\renewcommand*{\insertchapterspace}{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}}


\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\foreach \x in {1,...,10} {%
  \chapter{Foo \x}
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{Foo figure \x}
   \end{figure}
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{Foo other figure \x}
  \end{figure}
 }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The original definition  of `\insertchapterspace` is rejected in the abntex2, I tried this. But, I did not know the pgffor package.  The publishers will allow this because each university has its rules. Thank you for the help.

Comment: The pgffor package is just to produce a lot of fake figure environments instead of typing them.