# Equal spacing for lists of tables

Tags: tables, spacing, table-of-contents, lists

I use the following snippet to automatically generate list of tables in my document:

```
\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\singlespacing
\listoftables
```

[image: The result]

As can be seen, the resulting items have different spacings based on their chapters. How can I make all of them equally spaced? Like this:

[image: expected]

Comment: As always on this site please provide a full (but minimal) example that others can copy and test as is. Here we have to add a lot of stuff before your code can be tested, and thus a lot of people will just ignore your question. Many classes have a feature where each new chapter writes some vertical space to the lot and lof. But since you give absolutely no information about the setup you are using we cannot say for sure.

Comment: This answer to an earlier question might be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69327

Answer (score 2):

The `\chapter` command puts space into the LoF and LoT for each chapter using the macro `\addvspace`, which is also used in other places. I originally suggested in your preamble put

```
\renewcommand{\addvspace}{}
```

which is likely to have some unexpected side effects.

In  the `memoir` class (a superset of `book` and `report`) the chapter spacing in the LoF, LoT, etc is controlled by the `\insertchapterspace` macro which calls on `\addvspace`. With this class, in your preamble put

```
\renewcommand{\insertchapterspace}{}
```

which will result in no chapter spaces in the tables.

Comment: Oh, this is as wrong as it could be! You're advising to redefine a kernel macro that's used is *several* places and not only in the lists of figures and similar places.

Comment: @egreg I did not know that. I'll change my answer on the assumption that the OP could use the `memoir` class which has a macro`\insertchapterspace` for controlling chapter spacing in the LoF, LoT, etc. which involves no changes to `\addvspace`.