# The line spacing in the list of algorithms

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, algorithms

This is my code:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book} 
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
 \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
 \begin{document}
 \begin{spacing}{1.2}
 \tableofcontents
 \backmatter 
 {\listoffigures  \listoftables \listofalgorithms} \end{spacing}
 \include{Chapter1}
 \include{Chapter2}
 \end{document}
```

in the PDF file, i have: in the list of figure the space between fig2.1 and fig 2.2 is smaller than the space between fig2.2 and fig 3.1, but in the list of algorithm i have the same space everywhere, Have you an idea please ?

I would like to have the list of algorithms like the list of figure
Thank you.

Similar:

- [How to change the line spacing in my list of figures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/784/14996)
- [How to tweak the LOF and LOT without using any packages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97289/14996)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A patch to correct for this behaviour is provided by the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox). The default `\chapter` inserts a `10pt` vertical gap between chapter breaks in the LoF and LoT. Merely add a similar gap as part of the macro `\@chapter` to the LoA:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}% <cmd>
  {\chaptermark{#1}}% <search>
  {\chaptermark{#1}%
   \addtocontents{loa}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}% replace
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listofalgorithms
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{An algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{An algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{An algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{An algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

The original `\@chapter` command contains:

```
%...
\chaptermark{#1}%
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
%...
```

The `\patchcmd` searches for `\chaptermark{#1}` in `\@chapter` and replaces it with

```
\chaptermark{#1}%
\addtocontents{loa}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
```

effectively inserting the necessary chapter-wise gap in the LoA.

---

Make sure to load any package that affects the sectional unit `\chapter` *after* performing this patch. This is especially true if you use [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and [`minitoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/minitoc). Other sectional packages like [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) would not be compatible with the above patch.

Comment: i have added your code: \usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}% <cmd>
  {\chaptermark{#1}}% <search>
  {\chaptermark{#1}%
   \addtocontents{loa}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}% replace
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother  but the list of algorithm still the same!

Comment: @researcher: Using your MWE with the added code? If so, why does mine show a gap? If not, what else are you loading? You could test whether the patch was successful or not, by using `\patchcmd{..}{..}{..}{\typeout{success}}{\typeout{failure}}` and then checking your `.log` file for the word `success` or `failure`.

Comment: I have the same issue as the OP. The fix works in the MWE, but when I add it to main project, I get a 'failure'. I guess this is because I am loading other packages (and quite a few).

Comment: @Occams_Trimmer: Can you provide the detail to replicate the issue? The solution I provide relies on matching `\chaptermark{#1}` within `\@chapter` in order to add the spacing to the ToC. If `\chaptermark{#1}` doesn't exist in `\@chapter`, or `\@chapter` isn't used in the process of setting a chapter, then the patch won't work. But there are other work-arounds.

Comment: I managed to isolate it to the pdfx package, which loads hyperref. I followed your suggestion at the end of answer and it now works.