# How to tweak the LOF and LOT without using any packages?

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

The list of figures/tables in default `book` class looks like:

Default looking:

> ```
> List of Figures
>
>    1.1 Snapshots ..................  2
>    1.2 Snapshots ..................  4
>    1.3 Snapshots ..................  6
>    2.1 Snapshots .................. 12
>    2.2 Snapshots .................. 23
>    2.3 Snapshots .................. 32
> ```

What I want to tweak is like:

> ```
> List of Figures
>
>    Figure 1.1 Snapshots ..................  2
>    Figure 1.2 Snapshots ..................  4
>    Figure 1.3 A very long caption:  blabla 
>               blabla blabla ..............  6
>    % skip = 1em
>    Figure 2.1 Snapshots .................. 12
>    Figure 2.2 Snapshots .................. 23
>    Figure 2.3 Snapshots .................. 32
> ```

1. Group Figures/Tables by chapter with a small skip `1 em`
2. Add `Figure` or `Table` before each entries.

So how to implement this?

**Update 1:**

[image]

Using the codes by Werner, the `Figure` and `Table`  are appended to the begin of LOT, LOF entries, however, the captions are not aligned, how to solve this minor issue?

Similar:

- [How to change the line spacing in my list of figures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/784/14996)
- [The line spacing in the list of algorithms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88562/14996)

Comment: The default `book` class *does* add space between entries in the LoF & LoT (`10pt`). You must be doing something different to have no space between chapter-specific floats.

Comment: request number 2 is quite similar to [Add the word "Algorithm" before each entry in the List of Algorithms](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96969)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The default [`book`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) *does* insert a gap in the LoF & LoT between every chapter. See the chapter-making macro from `book.cls`:

   ```
   \def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                          \if@mainmatter
                            \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                            \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                      {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                          \else
                            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                          \fi
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                       \fi
                       \chaptermark{#1}%
                       \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}% Insert gap in LoF
                       \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}% Insert gap in LoT
                       \if@twocolumn
                         \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                       \else
                         \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                         \@afterheading
                       \fi}
   ```

   If you wish to change this to `1em`, you can use [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to patch `\@chapter` or, without package, copy the definition of `\@chapter` and replace the `\addvspace` lengths with `1em`. Here's the `etoolbox` patch:

   ```
   \usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
   \makeatletter
   % \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
   \patchcmd{\@chapter}{10\p@}{1em}{}{}% for List of Figures
   \patchcmd{\@chapter}{10\p@}{1em}{}{}% for List of Tables
   \makeatother
   ```
2. Adding `Figure` and `Table` before your LoF and LoT entries, respectively, follows a similar discussion as can be found in [Add the word “Algorithm” before each entry in the List of Algorithms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96969/5764):

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass[oneside]{book}
   \newcommand{\myfig}{\begin{figure}\caption{A figure caption}\end{figure}}
   \newcommand{\mytab}{\begin{table}\caption{A table caption}\end{table}}
   \let\oldlistoffigures\listoffigures
   \let\oldlistoftables\listoftables
   \renewcommand{\listoffigures}{%
     \begingroup%
     \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
     \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
     \oldlistoffigures%
     \endgroup}%
   \renewcommand{\listoftables}{%
     \begingroup%
     \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
     \renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline}%
     \oldlistoftables%
     \endgroup}%
   \begin{document}
   \listoffigures
   \listoftables
   \chapter{A chapter}\myfig\mytab\myfig\mytab\myfig\mytab
   \chapter{A chapter}\myfig\mytab\myfig\mytab\myfig\mytab
   \chapter{A chapter}\myfig\mytab\myfig\mytab\myfig\mytab
   \chapter{A chapter}\myfig\mytab\myfig\mytab\myfig\mytab
   \chapter{A chapter}\myfig\mytab\myfig\mytab\myfig\mytab
   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: It works, however, the Figs/Tabs captions are not aligned in terms of  vertical position, how to figure this out?

Comment: Could you figure it out @KOF?

Comment: @P.Leibner: If you have a similar issue to KOF's in terms of the *horizontal* alignment/indentation/hang of the entries in the LoF/LoT, please post a new question and provide a complete, minimal example that replicates the results.

Comment: Thanks @Werner, I ended up solving my issue using the titletoc package.