# How do I modify the default chapter headings and table of contents?

Tags: sectioning

I'm in the process of converting some lecture notes into TeX format, however I've run into a slight problem. Although the report document class is ideal for what I'm doing (a 100 page two-column document with chapters, sections and subsections), I need to modify the table of contents and chapter headings to display the chapters in terms of lectures instead of chapters.

So, for example, instead of the heading saying:

> Chapter 1:
>
> Title of the First Lecture

It should say:

> Lecture 1:
>
> Title of the First Lecture

And in the table of contents, instead of having:

> 1 Title of the First Lecture

It should have:

> Lecture 1 Title of the First Lecture

I'm looking for the cleanest and simplest way possible of doing this.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) In this site, upvoting and/or accepting an answer shows your appreciation to answers that you find useful, so there is no need to say "thank you" or its equivalent in your posts. Again, welcome!

Comment: Perhaps this post will help you: [How to change the name of document elements like "Figure", "Contents", "Bibliography" etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993). If it does, please tell us. `:-)`

Comment: That worked perfectly for the chapter heading, but I couldn't find any way to solve the table of contents problem :(

Comment: Look at the answers here: [Table of Contents with Chapter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39153)

Comment: For the second part, [Table of Contents with Chapter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39153/5764) provides a solution using [`titletoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc), while [How to tweak the LOF and LOT without using any packages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97289/5764) provides a means without using packages.