# List of algorithms, formatting

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, memoir, algorithms

I have the following MWE with `\listoffigures` and `\listofalgorithms`. In the output, the list of figures are grouped based on the chapter they are in. However, when I add list of algorithms with the algorithms numbered based on the chapters they are defined in (using `\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}`), it is not grouped at all. Is there some way to display it grouped as in `\listoffigures`?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listofalgorithms

\chapter{First chapter}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
  \caption{Another algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\section{Next section}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \caption{Another figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
  \caption{An algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
  \caption{Another algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\section{Next section}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \caption{Another figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
  \caption{An algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this manually as part of `\insertchapterspace`. So, within your preamble, add

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\insertchapterspace{%
  \addtocontents{loa}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}}
\makeatother
```

For the default document classes, see [The line spacing in the list of algorithms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88562/5764).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Werner! I have a related question: this fix does not seem to work with the document class 'report'. Is there a fix there?

Comment: @Occams_Trimmer: Correct. For that, see [The line spacing in the list of algorithms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88562/5764).