# extra line in table of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, line-spacing, texmaker

[image: This is my problem]

After the last figure of each chapter adds an extra line for me is bad. How I can fix?

Attached my configuration.

Thank you.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[english, spanish]{babel} % espanol
\usepackage{inputenc} % acentos  sin codigo
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} %imagenes
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.jpg}

\usepackage{geometry} %  margenes para encuadernacion
\geometry{bindingoffset=2cm}
\geometry{textwidth=390pt}

\usepackage{color} % para el color de fondo y letras
\definecolor{gris}{gray}{0.5}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{verbatim} % para la letra tipo consola
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % para que ponga 1.1.1.1 en subsubsecciones
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % para que ponga subsubsecciones en el indice

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document

\pagestyle{headings} % establece el estilo como book
\pretolerance=10000 % se usa para no separar palabras se-pa-ra-cion
\tolerance=10000

\usepackage{longtable}  %longuitud de las tablas (tabla 4.1 muy ancha)

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,%
    citecolor=black,%
    filecolor=black,%
    linkcolor=black,%
    urlcolor=black
}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\RequirePackage{wboiboites}
\definecolor{itcrtxtcolor}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\newboxedtheorem[boxcolor=gray, 
                 background=gray!15, 
                 titlebackground=gray!5,
                 titleboxcolor = black]
                 {Ejemplo}{Ejemplo}{thm}

\addto\captionsspanish{% Sirve para cambiar las traducciones que vienen en LATEX
\def\bibname{Referencias}%
\def\tablename{Tabla}%
}

\begin{document}
 ...
```

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, This solution helped me [How to change the line spacing in my list of figures?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/784/how-to-change-the-line-spacing-in-my-list-of-figures)