# Spacing in list of algorithms within classicthesis template

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, classicthesis

Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

Differently than `\listoffigures`, `\listoftables` or `\lstlistoflistings`, the `\listofalgorithmes` command is adding an extra white space between chapters in the `classicthesis` template.

I fixed it by adding two simple lines from a [nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/793/9167):

```
\newcommand*{\noaddvspace}{\renewcommand*{\addvspace}[1]{}}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\noaddvspace}
```

**Questions:**

- Is there a more elegant way to fix the spacing in the `scrreprt` class itself?
- Should this inconsistency be reported to `classicthesis` or `scrreprt` maintainers?

Comment: The inconsistency is a minor bug, but nonetheless you should tell the package maintainers about it.

Comment: @RüdigerVoigt, the question is, `classicthesis` or `scrreprt` maintainers?

Comment: Since `classicthesis` redefines stuff beyond recognition, this should be addressed to the maintainer of classicthesis. But as always, i recommend to drop this template.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug report for the package.