# Increase spacing between entries in LOT and LOF

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I am modifying a thesis template to satisfy the format requirements of my school. They ask for a single-line spacing within a entry in 'LoT/LoF', but require an extra line spacing between each entry. Something like (for example 'Figure 1.1's name is more than 1 line):

```
               List of Figures
1.1 aaa  
aaaa    

1.2 bbb    

1.3 ccc
```

I looked into the `.cls`-file and changed the line spacing format for 'LoT/LoF' to be single-lined spacing. But I do not know how to increase the spacing between each entry. Right now, my file looks like [image]

Here is some related MWE I have (I paste the whole unmeethesis.cls file here: http://pastebin.com/i2NfxHUf. Also need to create a file called unm12.clo to compile this, which is in the comment (I cannot add two links as a new user to the community)) :

```
\documentclass[botnum, fleqn]{unmeethesis}


\begin{document}
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}%
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\mainmatter
\chapter{AAA}
\section{aaa}
\begin{table*}[!ht]
\caption{Sample Table 1, a very very very very  looooooooooong name for example}
\end{table*}

\begin{table*}[!ht]
\caption{Sample Table 2}
\end{table*}
\section{bbb}

\chapter{BBB}
\section{aaa}
\section{bbb}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you should make your MWE fully compilable (`\documentclass[]{}...`) this way the community can help you much better.

Comment: @naphaneal i wanted to include as much as I can, but it is just too long from other school's thesis template. I will edit the post to include more. Thank you.

Comment: @H.Bai: We may need access to `thesis.cls`. You can paste it as separate pastes at [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and provides links to those files here.

Comment: @Werner I paste the whole .cls file here: http://pastebin.com/i2NfxHUf. It is a little bit messy, with a lot of re-definition. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/784/how-to-change-the-line-spacing-in-my-list-of-figures

Comment: Can you please make a compilable MWE? We don't have you input files. And without them, there are no entries in the toc to show your problem. Furthermore it does not compile due to missing `\title`.

Comment: I had the same issue for my university's template (which I finally fixed). It's best to use the `tocloft` package to do this job.

Comment: @samcarter Thanks for your reply. I modified the MWE, Now it should be compilable, but you have to create a new file called unm12.clo from http://pastebin.com/suJ6uRbb (I could not add two links as a new user to the community). Also, I tried that link you provided, that is related to the space between each chapter in LoT. What I want is to increase the space between each entry in LoT, not only each chapter.

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this solve your question?

```
\documentclass[botnum, fleqn]{unmeethesis}

\begin{document}
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}%
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
{
\setlength{\parskip}{20pt}
\listoftables
}
\listoffigures
\mainmatter
\chapter{AAA}
\section{aaa}
\begin{table*}[!ht]
\caption{Sample Table 1, a very very very very  looooooooooong name for example}
\end{table*}

\begin{table*}[!ht]
\caption{Sample Table 2}
\end{table*}
\section{bbb}

\chapter{BBB}
\section{aaa}
\section{bbb}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This pretty much works!! All I need is to adjust the vertical position of LoT and LoF a little bit. Thanks so much. BTW, since you set parskip, does that mean each entry in LoT/LoF is treated as a paragraph?

Comment: @H.Bai If you want to reduce the space between the headline and the lot, try `\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{-20pt}}
\listoftables`.  I guess they might be individual paragraphs, but I don't know for sure.